# Passing $_GET parameters on page reload

Tags: php, forms, redirect

I am trying to make it so when the page reloads it redirects me with the same $_GET parameters as the previous page. Right now I am trying to use header to achieve this, but when I submit my form the variable $id is blank.

**HTML Form**

```
<form action = "." method ="post">
<input type = "text" name = "username">
<textarea name = "comments"></textarea>
<input type = "hidden" name = "action" value = "posts"> 
<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Add Post">
</form>
```

**Redirect Script**

```
if ( empty( $_GET ) && !empty($_POST) ){
if($action == 'posts'){
if(!isset($_GET['thread'])){
$id = $_GET['thread'];
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'?thread='.$id);
}   
}
```

Thanks for anyone who replies!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: you also posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002265/passing-variables-through-get-and-displaying-on-the-url-of-another-page being a possible exact duplicate.

Comment: I don't really understand your logic here... You only want to get the value in `$_GET['thread']` if it's *not* set?

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect script doesn't make a lot of sense. Try this, maybe

```
if ( empty( $_GET ) && !empty($_POST) ){
    if(isset($_POST['thread'])){
        $id = $_POST['thread'];
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .'?thread='.$id);
    }   
}
```